# Парсинг json android

Tags: json, android, синтаксический-анализ

Во всех примерах в начале стоит вот такого вида конструкция {data:[{....}..
Как парсить такой JSON?

```
[
{"id":"99111772",
"name":"Иванов Иван Иванович",
"position":"Депутат ГД",
"isCurrent":true,
"factions":[
{"id":"72100004",
"name":"Фракция Политической партии \"Коммунистическая партия Российской Федерации    \"",
"startDate":"2011-12-04",
"endDate":"2017-01-03"}]},

{"id":"99112284",
"name":"Петров Петр Петрович",
"position":"Депутат ГД",
"isCurrent":true,
"factions":[
{"id":"72100024",
"name":"Фракция Всероссийской политической партии \"ЕДИНАЯ РОССИЯ\"",
"startDate":"2013-03-06",
"endDate":"2017-01-03"}]}]
```

Делаю вот так:

```
                    deputies = new ArrayList<String>();

                    try {
                        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray(null);
                        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject name = data.getJSONObject(i);
                            String n = name.getString("name");
                            deputies.add(n);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Что мне писать в это строчке кода, null, как я понял, не катит? Или проблема не только в этой строчке? объясните пожалуйста)

```
JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray(null)
```

Comment: Вам надо сам json передать как строку в объект

Answer (score 1):

Знак `[]` - означает что это массив. По сути у вас такие Java классы

```
public class Member {
   String id;
   String name;
   String position;
   boolean isCurrent;
   ArrayList<Fraction> fractions;
}

public class Fraction {
   String id;
   String name;
   Date startDate;
   Date endDate;
}
```

Чтобы распарсить вам надо использовать [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) и вызвать примерно такой код:

```
Type memberType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Member>>(){}.getClass();
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<Member> members = gson.fromJson(jsonString, memberType);
```

`members` и будет содержать нужный массив объектов

Answer (score -1):

Вот [здесь](http://lib365.ru/android/8) посмотрите, из строки показан перевод в объект и массив json.

---

Для чтения json ответов от сервера, необходимо импортировать org.json. библиотеку.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Метод принимает входящий параметр строку формата json, далее создается объект, из него массив. Имя "data" - есть именем json-массива пришедшего с сервера. Далее в нужные нам места вытягиваем значение элементов по идентификаторам, к примеру как "flag".

```
public void JSONURL(String result) {

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        final JSONArray urls = json.getJSONArray("data");
        FLAG = urls.getJSONObject(0).getString("flag").toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
}
```